# Counting list elements from ajax response

Tags: jquery

**jQuery**

```
$.ajax({
    url : "/assets/inc/list.php",
    success : function (data) {
        console.log($(data).filter('li').size());
    }
});
```

Using the above I have tried the total number of list items in that php as the response puts back a list of

```
<li>
```

with content inside them

but I get a console.log  error of

> Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:

which has my list echoed afterwards.

**example of data**

```
<li>
    <strong>Company Name</strong>
    123 Fake Street<br />
    Fakesville<br />
    <a href="#">Link</a>
</li>
<li>
    <strong>Company Name</strong>
    123 Fake Street<br />
    Fakesville<br />
    <a href="#">Link</a>
</li>
<li>
    <strong>Company Name</strong>
    123 Fake Street<br />
    Fakesville<br />
    <a href="#">Link</a>
</li>
<li>
    <strong>Company Name</strong>
    123 Fake Street<br />
    Fakesville<br />
    <a href="#">Link</a>
</li>
<li>
    <strong>Company Name</strong>
    123 Fake Street<br />
    Fakesville<br />
    <a href="#">Link</a>
</li>
```

Comment: can you show a sample of data?

Comment: *Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:* means that jQuery tries to evaluate `data` as selector. If you are using jQuery 1.9, try `$($.parseHTML(data))` instead. For more info, have a look at http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-htmlstring-versus-jquery-selectorstring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this. This takes the data and only counts the line items within it. Here is the [doc](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
$.ajax({
    url : "/assets/inc/list.php",
    success : function (data) {
        console.log($(data).find('li').length);
    }
});
```

Comment: There error has nothing to do with `.filter` or `.size` though, so changing those should not make a difference.

Comment: The filter call did not cause the error but the $(data) call which is still in place. You probably fixed the markup returned in the meantime.

Comment: How do I find length if returned data looks like this `<div class="searchResultBox">...........</div>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

***JS CODE***

```
$.ajax({
    url : "/assets/inc/list.php",
    success : function (data) {
        console.log($(data).find('li').length);
    }
});
```

Comment: This error may occur `TypeError: Property 'length' of object [object Object] is not a function` Use `length` instead of `length()`

Answer (score 0):

The "Syntax error" comes from the `$(data)` part which means that `data` contains malformed markup code. You need to fix this at the server side.

Comment: What should I do If the returned data contains HTML markup code, and I need to find the length by class name.